# Tem como fazer uma chamada JavaScript pelo PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou em uma duvida ... Tenho um código PHP, e quando ele chegar no "fim dele" gostaria de chamar um JavaScript!

Ex:

```
<?
   ....
   sucesso('$a','$b');
?>

<script language="javascript">

function sucesso(a,b){
...
}
</script>
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "chamar um javascript"? Qual o comportamento que você quer chegar?

Comment: Não é possível. Você pode fazer o javascript realizar uma chamada assíncrona ao PHP via Ajax para obtenção dos parâmetros.

Comment: @FábioLemosElizandro como demonstra o meu exemplo, eu gostaria que o php' "executasse" o javascript quando estivesse no fim!

Comment: @Beterraba como você diz que não é possivel realizar tal maneira .. Como eu deveria realizar o método que você mencionou?

Comment: @Bruno o ideal seria saber o que você quer fazer, para saber qual meio utilizar, se é uma chamada AJAX ou se da para resolver tudo com JS ou outro meio...

Comment: O que parece estar acontecendo é uma confusão de tecnologias. Como apontado pelo @Inkeliz, Javascript é executado pelo cliente; PHP, pelo servidor. Se seu script PHP possui situações críticas (validação de entradas, possibilidade de lançamento de exceções, indisponibilidade de outros servidores/serviços, etc...), ou seja, não há certeza sobre o resultado do processo, englobe o bloco que chama o Javascript em um if (como o Inkeliz fez) porque, quando o usuário receber a página no lado cliente, este script só rodará caso o processo tenha resultado em sucesso.

Comment: Por outro lado, se foi o lado cliente quem solicitou a execução do PHP (via "AJAX" ou similar) e este script de servidor não fornece HTML como retorno (ou seja, a resposta se dá através de XML, JSON, texto plano ou qualquer outro formato), basta que a resposta do PHP explicite o resultado (`echo "<sucesso />"` ou semelhante) e que o Javascript, ao receber a resposta do AJAX, verifique por si (em um if nesse cliente) se a resposta do servidor foi de sucesso, e então providenciar a chamada à função.

Comment: @RuiPimentel o servidor pode fornecer HTML tranquilamente para uma requisição AJAX. Acho que o que está faltando nessa pergunta é um pouco de fundamento, objetivo. O que ele quer fazer a gente sabe que não é possível, mas podemos ajudar se soubermos o motivo

Comment: Como você não explica o problema real que está tentando resolver (não o bug do código), cada resposta oferece uma alternativa diferente. Recomendado: [**O que é o “problema XY”?**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy)

Answer (score 2):

Tentou:

```
<?php

   ...

   echo '<script language="javascript">';
   echo '    alert("fim");';
   echo '</script>';
```

Desculpe, mas não consigo pensar em nada mais "elegante".

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="javascript">
function sucesso(a,b){
alert(a+b);
}
</script>

<?php
    $a = 2; 
    $b = 3;
    echo "<script>";
    echo "sucesso(".$a.",".$b.");";
    echo "</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Por que votaram contra? Ok, não tem explicação nem os devidos alertas de que fazer isso provavelmente é um caminho ruim, mas é a única resposta que traz uma solução aplicada ao exemplo da pergunta...

Comment: @bfavaretto, exato, a única. Eu não consegui fazer o *parse* do objetivo do autor, `<loop>` [ele fala de **X** mas eu só vejo **Y**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32062/tem-como-fazer-uma-chamada-javascript-pelo-php#comment60764_32122) `</warning>`

Comment: Sem dúvida a pergunta tem esse problema, @brasofilo

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar:

```
<? 
if($a and $b){ //se A e B
?>

<script>
alert('hello');//javascript
</script>

<?
} //fim se
?>
```

Mas, o alert (ou qualquer comando) será emitido no lado do cliente, e não pelo PHP. Você pode utilizar "echo", mas acho melhor da forma acima.

Answer (score 1):

No WordPress, valores são passados do PHP pro JavaScript usando "localização", que é imprimir na `<head>` do documento um objeto PHP->JS, e os scripts chamados após a localização vão usar esse objeto para resgatar os valores. Segue um exemplo básico.

PHP/HTML no arquivo `teste.php`:

```php
<?php
$a = 'valor 1';
$b = 'valor 2';
?><!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Teste PHP/JS</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var teste_obj = {
        'a': '<?php echo $a; ?>', 
        'b': '<?php echo $b; ?>' 
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#"id="play" onclick="teste_func();">Valor do objeto</a>
    <script src="teste.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

E o JS no arquivo `teste.js`:

```javascript
function teste_func() {
    alert( 'A:' + teste_obj.a + '\r\nB: ' + teste_obj.b );
}
```

Comment: Bom, não respondo exatamente [ao que autor perguntou](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32062/tem-como-fazer-uma-chamada-javascript-pelo-php/32122#comment60691_32123), mas como faltou [explicar o problema que estava tentando resolver](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy), apareceu esta salada de fruta de respostas diferentes; ficam aí como alternativas aos futuros visitantes que estiverem procurando algo parecido.

Comment: muito bem colocado... Se não conseguirmos ajudar o autor, pelo menos ajudaremos todas as outras pessoas do universo :) hahahah!

Comment: @RuiPimentel, agora mesmo tava no SOen procurando umas coisas, e as respostas que me ajudaram eram umas que tavam lá pelo meio do campo (nums posts de 2, 3 anos atrás) :)

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei até aonde em termos técnicos, de lógica e de segurança isso é recomendável mas eu mesmo faço muito isso só pra dar um alert e as vezes redirecionar o script até mesmo por causa de erros de headers que eu decido não tratar. Um exemplo:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$logout = TRUE;

if($logout == FALSE){

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Você foi deslogado com sucesso');";
    echo "location.href='http://google.com.br';";
    echo "</script>";

} else {

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "alert('Você foi deslogado com sucesso');";
    echo "location.href='http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32062/tem-como-fazer-uma-chamada-javascript-pelo-php#32062';";
    echo "</script>";

}

?>
```

Ver [link](http://axitech.com.br/vista/logout.php) exemplo do script. Independente do tipo de trabalho que tenha que fazer é sempre possível puxar javascript, jquery ou qualquer extensão de javascript dentro do código PHP.

Comment: Marcos, alguns usuários com pontuação suficiente para visualizar respostas excluídas sinalizaram que sua resposta é boa e poderia contribuir para a questão, apenas ressaltando que os erros com o `header` é porque provavelmente tem algum conteúdo sendo escrito antes, e o `header` deve ser a primeiro coisa a ser executada no servidor. Você não gostaria de **desfazer a exclusão**?

Comment: Essa é uma abordagem muito interessante, porém, o exemplo não foi dos melhores, mas vale +1

Comment: @Marcos Vinicius Nasc. Pereira, seus 2 ifs geram um alerta "Você foi deslogado com sucesso", acho que esqueceu de alterar o texto.